# TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object - validation of email addresses

Tags: python, regex, csv

I'm using to validate email addresses from a CSV file using Regular Expressions. I am using the following code for the above requirement.

```
@staticmethod
def emailValidReg(input):
    with open('simple_rule.txt', 'r') as content_file:
        content = content_file.read()
    if re.search(content, input):
        return True
    else:
        return False

@staticmethod
def validation(src):
    df = pd.read_csv(src)
    df = df.copy();

    df["Email_validate"] = df["email"].apply(Validator.emailValidReg)
    df_filtered = df[df['Email_validate']]
    del df_filtered["Email_validate"]
    df_filtered.to_csv('email_validator_reg.csv')

i = Validator()
i.validation('test.csv')
```

**simple_rule.txt**

```
[a-zA-Z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~.-]+@[a-zA-Z-]+\.[a-z]
```

The following is coming when the code runs.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/RegexExercise/Validator.py", line 57, in <module>
    i.validation('sample.csv')
  File "E:/RegexExercise/Validator.py", line 43, in validation
    df["Email_validate"] = df["email"].apply(Validator.emailValidReg)
  File "E:\RegexExercise\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 3848, in apply
    mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
  File "pandas\_libs\lib.pyx", line 2327, in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer
  File "E:/RegexExercise/Validator.py", line 33, in emailValidReg
    if re.search(content, input):
  File "C:\Users\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\re.py", line 183, in search
    return _compile(pattern, flags).search(string)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

The CSV file I used is `sample.csv` and the regex file is `simple_rule.txt`. The py class is `Validator`.

Can someone please explain why this happens and a tip to resolve the issue. I tried to read and understand similar error given questions but the cases were different and it was a bit hard to understand. Please help me!

Comment: The basics is that one of (content, input) is not a string, I suggest you try to print them or put a breakpoint there to see which one is wrong and why

Comment: You are using pandas to read the CSV file? The docs for [`DataFrame.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) staste that the function receives a **`Series`** object, which is obviously neither a string nor a  bytes.like object. You need to convert that value into a python string/bytes. Are you sure you need to use pandas to do this? Is Python's built-in csv module too slow or are you doing some other processing of that data?

Comment: I am required for the same task using both methods. The task is already done using email_validator which is the in-built method in pandas.

Comment: I copied all the csv data and pasted on a new csv. Then it worked! Do you know why is that? when i enter data into the sample csv and deleted them for testing after deletion data type of empty raws (where i deleted the data previously) was indicated as Nan.

Comment: I am confused with all of this strange scenarios